# While loop if statement NULL issue

Tags: php

I can't seem to get this figured out. What am I doing wrong? I have a table in my database and some rows have an empty column for the "company" field.

I'm trying to get the "Users own uploaded files in the html table below. It belongs with "1629"

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";

$query = "SELECT company, dmy, COUNT(company) FROM AdTracking WHERE DATE(dmy) = CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY company";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<div style='margin-top:100px;'><center><h2>";
echo date('l jS \ F Y');
echo "<br />";
echo "</h2><center></div>";


echo '
<center> <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
';

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($row['company'] == NULL) {
        echo "Users own uploaded files";
    };

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><strong>" . $row['company'] . "</strong></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(company)'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


echo '
    </tbody>
</table> </center>
';



?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing outside of td and tr.

You have maintain format .

Try like this

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><strong>" .($row['company'] == NULL ? "Users own uploaded files" : $row['company']). "</strong></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(company)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've tried this but it's now taking all the companies out of the html table.

Comment: Never mind! just saw you updated! It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: Will do! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if (!$row['company']) // it check null or have something value
        $value = "Users own uploaded files";
   else 
       $value = $row['company'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><strong>" . $value . "</strong></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(company)'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

> **use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql because "mysql" is deprected.**

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I really need to start doing that. Is mysqli a total difference from mysql?

Comment: No,mysqli support all the method of "mysql" like mysqli_connect,mysqli_select_db

Comment: and yes you also use mysql as a object oriented like mysqli = new mysqli(); so you can use mysqli as procedure or object oriented.and more secure using prepare statement.